# Microsoft Access 2013 sql return which table information came from

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am re-making a data base to store an inventory of ID numbers, Locations, and Item type. In my older data base there are a number of tables (16) or so. I have written code to produce a list of all items in the data base (around 1500) and produce the location of where they are.

Where i am having problems is I do not know how to make my data base produce which table each item came from. by this i mean i would like my code to produce the item tag(which it does), the items location(which it does), and which table the information came from(which it does not). I would like it to be a new column in the return. 
thank you for any help. Here is an sample example of what my current code looks like. This is only one of the many unions i have

SELECT [Phones].[IT Tag], Phones.Location, from [Phones]
UNION  ...

I would like something like this to work

//it tag and Locations are valid columns in my database table name should show phones for this select statement nd each statement after this should produce the correct table name.

SELECT [Phones].[IT Tag], Phones.Location,Phones.TableName from [Phones]
UNION ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the table name into the individual queries:

```
select 'foo' as tablename from foo
union all
select 'bar' as tablename from bar
union all
etc...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly